# Show such cyclic's representation is unique and irreducible

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a cyclic of order 3 generated by $a$. And if we have a 2-dimensional rational representation $\pi(a) = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then it is unique and irreducible.

To check it's unique I think we only need to compute the $\pi(a^2)$ and $\pi(a^3)$, right?

But about the irreducibility, I think it should be easy but have no clue how to prove something is irreducible.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying that is unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using complex numbers, A cyclic group is abelian and abelian groups only admit irreducible representations on dimension one.

In the rational case, let $A = \pi(a)$, one can see that
$$
 p(x) = \det(A - x) = \lambda^2 + \lambda + 1
$$
does not have any rational roots (In the complex numbers, the roots are  the roots of the unity $1,\omega,\omega^2$ satisfying $\omega^3 =1$). Since $A$ does not have any one dimensional invariant subspace there can't be a one dimensional invariant subspace for $G$ and this representation is irreducible. I don't know what do you mean by unique, since any representation could be conjuged to get another different representation, e.g. $g \mapsto U\pi(g)U^{-1}$ for any invertible matrix $U$.

Comment: That's correct, however, this question limits the representation as rational representation, aka on $Q$ rather than $C$, hence the Schur's lemma doesn't hold here.

Comment: In that case, try finding invariant subspaces for $\pi(a)$ and $\pi(a)^2$. Those are intrinsic and it will be easy to see that they are either orthogonal (or with trivial intersection) or the whole space.

Comment: I think I've solved it by finding the invariant subspaces. Would you mind add the computation for $\pi a$ so that I can check my understanding about the result (b-a, a) is full subspace is correct?